# View frame shows unexpected results on orientation change

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In portrait orientation, i have pushed the view contents up when keyboard appears and pushed it down on return key press.The view's frame is x=0, y=20 (status bar placed). In xib, the view size is set to freeform. When changed to landscape orientation, the new view's frame's origin is  x=20 y=0. Ideally it should be x=0 and y=20 right? Below is the code.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation

{

if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
   // [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];

}
else if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{
   // [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 480, 300)];
}
    return YES;

}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{

    [lblFirstName setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 134, 84, 21)]; 
    [lblLastName setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 193, 83, 21)];
    [txtFirstName setFrame:CGRectMake(273, 129, 142, 31)];
    [txtLastName setFrame:CGRectMake(273, 188, 142, 31)];
    [btnSubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(194, 243, 93, 37)];

}
else if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{

    [lblFirstName setFrame:CGRectMake(37, 198, 84, 21)]; 
    [lblLastName setFrame:CGRectMake(37, 282, 83, 21)];
    [txtFirstName setFrame:CGRectMake(165, 193, 127, 31)];
    [txtLastName setFrame:CGRectMake(165, 277, 127, 31)];
    [btnSubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(114, 349, 93, 37)];

}


}

//Hide keypad on background touch
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(self.view.frame.origin.y<0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
[self.view endEditing:YES];

//[self keyboardWillHide];

}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
if ([sender isEqual:txtLastName])
{
    //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
    NSLog(@"view frame original is %f %f",self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y);
    if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
}

}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden comes above the keyboard 
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= OFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += OFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
         //revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += OFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= OFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;
     NSLog(@"view frame modified is %f %f",self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y);

}];

}

//Return key click handled.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
if(self.view.frame.origin.y<0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}

[textField resignFirstResponder];

return YES;

}
```

Comment: Depending on constraints etc. in your xib file, the framework may apply changes after willRotoateToInterfaceOrientation. Try using didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation instead.

Comment: What kind of constraints? Could you please enlighten on it.

Comment: Did you try using didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation instead? I was referring to layout constraints that you can define within interface builder and that sort of define themselfs automatically when you don't care much.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in iOS7.
At the same time the same code works fine in iOS8.

To fix this issue you need to shift view.bounds instead of view.frame